# Twitter bootstrap and PHP session_start()

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a site at the moment with PHP and Twitter Bootstrap.

If I put `session_start()` first then the layout messes up because Bootstrap requires `<!DOCTYPE html>` first.

If I put `<!DOCTYPE html>` then I cant use sessions.

Index.php - sessions fail here :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php 
  ini_set('display_errors', 1);
  ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);

  require_once('../php/init.php');

  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

    $username = trim($_POST['username']);
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);
    $errors = [];

    if (empty($_POST['username'])) array_push($errors, 'A username is required');
    if (empty($_POST['password'])) array_push($errors, 'A password is required');

    if (empty($errors)) {
      echo 'No Errors';

      if (login($username, $password)) {
        echo 'Logged In';
      }
    }

  } 

?>
```

index.php - layout fails here:

```
<?php 

  ini_set('display_errors', 1);
  ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);

  require_once('../php/init.php');

  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

    $username = trim($_POST['username']);
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);
    $errors = [];

    if (empty($_POST['username'])) array_push($errors, 'A username is required');
    if (empty($_POST['password'])) array_push($errors, 'A password is required');

    if (empty($errors)) {
      echo 'No Errors';

      if (login($username, $password)) {
        echo 'Logged In';
      }
    }

  } 

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
```

init.php:

```
<?php

if (session_id() == "" || !isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
}

require 'database/connect.php';
require 'functions.php';
```

Any help is appreciated

Many Thanks

Jacob

Comment: *"If I put session_start() first then the layout messes up because Bootstrap requires <!DOCTYPE html> first."* - You need to post the actual code you tried; this is guesswork really.

Comment: *"because Bootstrap requires <!DOCTYPE html> first."* - That shouldn't matter. How you're using this and the file's extension are unknown. You're probably outputting before header also, who knows.

Comment: *If I put **<!DOCTYPE html>** then I cant use sessions.  *    

Why not?

Comment: Voted to close as unclear until we know exactly which animal(s) we're really dealing with here.

Comment: The longer you wait, the longer it takes for a solution. If you left the question only to return at a later date, then you'll have to ping someone, or wait for someone else to visit the question when you have edited it and provided actual syntax and how it's used. I for one have now left it.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your timely and helpful responses. Turns out I had some whitespace between the <?php ?> and <doctype> and it didnt like that.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better if you provided a sample of your code to understand the problem correctly. Using `session_start` before the `DOCTYPE` should not cause a problem but I will try to write a solution based on my understanding.

You can put like this having both on the same line with no spaces before or after.

```
<?php session_start(); ?><!DOCTYPE html>
```

It is better if you have a function that is responsible for header part

```
header() {
    include 'header.php';
}

bootstrap() {
    session_start();
    header();
    body();
    footer();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

  code...

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Turns out it doesnt like whitespace. The above worked. The below didnt work.

```
<?php 

  code...

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
```